# Something went wrong with Cordova when trying to build

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

As I mentioned in the question, when I try to build my project it gives an error:

> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 9 mins 33.837 secs
>   Error: /home/aqil/App/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>     Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApk'.
>     A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
>     Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'.
>     Could not resolve com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3.
>            Required by:
>                project :CordovaLib
>     Could not resolve com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3.
>     Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.7.3/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.pom'.
>     Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.7.3/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.pom'.
>     Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168.243.150] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

What's the problem with it, is it a gradle problem? I have downloaded the latest one, and included in my path, so what's wrong with it? I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: This line: `Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168.243.150] failed` tells, that a connection failed during the process. Maybe you need to run the command as sudo ?

Comment: something weird happen,whe i try sudo with cordova build android command it gives :  `aqil@dell:~/App$ sudo cordova build
Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory` but without sudo it give that error

Comment: @MatthiasGwiozda yes it's a connection problem, but OP should NOT run with sudo. It does not help for this problem and puts the system on risk to be compromised.

Comment: @AqilHex Do you access the internet via a proxy? maybe it is blocking your access to jcenter.bintray.com

Comment: @MatthiasGwiozda yes Mathew you right , as you said its connection problem ,and now its worked for me,because im iranian,we have some limitation so i tried Tor  VPN and its worked for me now.

Comment: for the first time its needed to downloade some neccessary files , but now it goes withour downloading and build my app safe and sound,thanks

Comment: For me, out of pure laziness I just tried to build 2-3 times and it eventually worked! Hooray for laziness :P